# Subprocess starting two processes instead of one

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using subprocess to start a process and let it run in the background, it's a server application. The process itself is a java program with a thin wrapper (which among other things, means that I can just launch it as an executable without having to call java explicitly).

I'm using Popen to run the process and when I set shell=False, it runs but it spawns two processes instead of one. The first process has init as its parent and when I inspect it via ps, it just displays the raw command. However, the second process displays with the expanded java arguments (-D and -X flags) - this is what I expect to see and how the process looks when I run the command manually.

Interestingly, when I set shell=True, the command fails. The command does have a help message but it doesn't seem to indicate that there's a problem with my argument list (there shouldn't be). Everything is the same except the shell named argument to Popen.
I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu. Not really sure what's going on here, any help is appreciated.  I suppose it's possible that the java command is doing an exec/fork and for some reason, the parent process isn't dying when I start it through Python.

I saw this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468922/python-why-does-subprocess-start-2-processes-in-ubuntu-and-1-in-opensuse) which looked promising but doesn't change the behavior that I'm experiencing.

Comment: This question is quite vague -- without having the source for both the wrapper and your invocation, any answer is guesswork. That being said, given the symptoms described, there's some fairly strong grounds to make such guesses educated.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually more of a question about the wrapper than about Python -- you would get the same behavior running it from any other language.

To get the behavior you want, the wrapper would want to have the line where it invokes the JVM look as follows:

```
exec java -D... -cp ... main.class.here "$@"
```

...as opposed to lacking the `exec` on front:

```
java -D... -cp ... main.class.here "$@"
```

In the former case, the process image of the wrapper is *replaced* with that of the JVM it invokes; in the latter, the wrapper waits for the JVM to exit, and then continues to run.

If the wrapper does any cleanup after JVM exit, using `exec` will prevent this from happening and would thus be the Wrong Thing -- in this case, you would *want* the wrapper to still exist while the JVM runs, as otherwise it would be unable to perform cleanup afterwards.

Be aware that if the wrapper is responsible for detaching the subprocess, it needs to be able to close open file handles for this to happen correctly. Consider passing `close_fds=True` to your Popen call if your parent process has more file descriptors than only stdin, stdout and stderr open.